# Pyspark inserting Time in Cassandra using datastax connector

Tags: pyspark, cassandra, datastax

I'm inserting data from Pyspark to Cassandra using:

com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.0

Among the variables that I'm inserting there is also the time, and the connector doesn't like it. 
If i tried to send: '16:51:35.634652' and i received the following error:

**com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConversionException: Cannot convert object 16:51:35.634652 of type class java.lang.String to java.lang.Long.**

Basically the converter doesn't like the string and it want to convert it to java.lang.long when actually in cassandra is time and in python is string.

I'm wondering how can i just bring the value on Cassandra without converting anything to Long, i don't think that converting time to long make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! I had a check on:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSupportedTypes.html

I found that: CQL timestamp -> SCALA: Long, java.util.Date, java.sql.Date, org.joda.time.DateTime

So i converted my variable

```
import datetime

date_time_1 = '11:12:27.243860'

date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Sent to the connector and everything is working fine!